# How can I perform a cache-optimised parallel 2D Matrix transpose in Rust?

Tags: matrix, rust, optimization, parallel-processing, transpose

The matrix size might be 1024x1024 as an example, and it is important that the data is actually transposed in memory, rather just having its indices swapped. What do I mean by cache-optimised? I mean that the transposing happens in 8x8 tiles to take advantage of the CPU cache.

Here is a parallel, cache optimized 2D matrix transpose in C. Notice that adding the single #pragma line (and enabling/linking to OpenMP) is all we need to acheive parallelism.

```c
void transpose(int64_t *restrict input, int64_t *restrict output, size_t w, size_t h) {
    #define TILE_SIZE 8
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) num_threads(8)
    for (size_t x0 = 0; x0 < w; x0 += TILE_SIZE) {
        for (size_t y0 = 0; y0 < h; y0 += TILE_SIZE) {
            for (size_t x = x0; x < x0 + TILE_SIZE && x < w; ++x) {
                for (size_t y = y0; y < y0 + TILE_SIZE && y < h; ++y) {
                    output[w*y + x] = input[h*x + y];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The equivalent (sequential, safe) Rust code looks something like this:

```rs
fn transpose(input: &[i64], output: &mut [i64], w: usize, h: usize) {
    assert!(input.len() >= w * h && output.len() >= w * h); // Ensures safety
    const TILE_SIZE: usize = 8;
    for x0 in (0..w).step_by(TILE_SIZE) {
        for y0 in (0..h).step_by(TILE_SIZE) {
            for x in (x0..x0 + TILE_SIZE).filter(|&x| x < w) {
                for y in (y0..y0 + TILE_SIZE).filter(|&y| y < h) {
                    unsafe {
                        // Skip bounds checks to match C-code and improve performance
                        *output.get_unchecked_mut(w*y + x) = *input.get_unchecked(h*x + y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My main problem trying to parallelize this is that I can't have multiple mutable references to the output slice.

Comment: More cache optimising is possible if you are prepared to first transpose tiles of size NxN chosen such that 2N tiles will fit into the next level cache. Then you shuffle the tiles into their final positions. That keeps most of the moves local. Easier said than done on a rectangular array (and restricts your matrix dimensions to multiples of N).